# ¿Cómo establecer permisos con Django Api Rest Framework?

Tags: django, api, djangorestframework, permisos

Mi problema o duda es como usar los permisos que tienen asignados los usuarios ya sean de grupo o permisos individuales, para que cuando un usuario se logea usando Django Rest Framework solo tenga acceso a las tablas a las cuales tenga permisos asignados.

Actualmente si me logueo tengo acceso a todas las tablas, sea usuario admin o cualquier otro. Si pueden darme un ejemplo, o mostrarme algún enlace donde se ejemplifica sería de mucha ayuda.

[image: accediendo con el usuario admin]

[image: accediendo con otro usuario con poco permisos llamado prueba]

Dejo el enlace del repositorio en github https://github.com/Weed-Nim/BillAPI.git

Para la programación utilice los serializer y viewsets en cada uno de las apps
[image: carpeta de la app de Articulos]

Aqui pongo imagenes del código:
[image: Modelo de la app de Artículos]
[image: serializador de la app articulo]
[image: Viewset de la app articulo]

PD: arriba esta el repositorio, solo pongo una vista rapida de como lo trabaje, aunque repito mi duda es como puedo hacer para que cuando un usuario se logea solo tenga acceso a las tablas las cuales tiene permisos (individuales o grupales) y no suceda lo de la imagen.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tal vez tengan acceso de solo lectura, sería bueno que nos eneseñes un poco de tu código

Comment: @CésarBustíos gracias por tu pronta respuesta, acabo de editar la pregunta, incorpore el enlace de github al repositorio del proyecto, ademas que agregue una capturas de pantalla para detallar mejor mi problema, asi tambien subi imagenes del codigo solo para dar una idea rapida de como lo programe, espero que esto sirva para que me puedas hechar una mano en este problema. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Nestor, antes de enviar un enlace al codigo o poner imágenes, siempre se prefiere que pegues el código en tu pregunta ya que es más facil de leer y entender. Sugiero que edites tu post con esos cambios, por lo menos la parte del código no la pongas como imagen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En Django Rest Framework, existen varios métodos para abordar el tema de permisos. A nivel básico, añades el atributo `permission_classes` a las clases que hereden de `APIView` para incluir los permisos de acceso. Los tipos de permisos que recibe este atributo están en `rest_framework.permissions`

Hay otra forma más avanzada de abordar los permisos y es creando clases de permisos que hereden de la clase base de Rest Framework (`rest_framework.permissions.BasePermission`). En este caso puedes hacer algo como:

```
class EditarObjecto(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # SAFE_METHODS son métodos de solo lectura
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        # Aqui comparamos el usuario del request
        return obj.usuario == request.user
```

Comment: Pero estos métodos heredan los permisos de lo usuarios de django o los permisos de REST frameworks?

Comment: Son de REST Framework