# Interactuando mi aplicación Django con aplicaciones externas

Tags: python, djangorestframework, django-models

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación Django, la cual tiene tres diferentes tipos de usuarios. Estos usuarios deben ser algo así como consumidos o utilizados por una aplicación externa a través de HTTP para el proceso de inicio de sesión y utilizar los datos asociados de estos usuarios.

Básicamente pensaría que mi aplicación Django sería algo como tipo Backend para que esta tercera aplicación la utilice.

¿Cómo puedo lograr exponer mis usuarios y demás modelos para que sean utilizados por terceros o por mi misma aplicación?.

Estoy explorando [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) y pienso que es una gran alternativa para ello, en cuanto a la autenticación, no se si opciones como `OAuth2` me ayuden a ello, [a juzgar por su documentación](https://django-oauth2-provider.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html) parece que se puede conseguir lo que deseo.

Mire [este post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/563/c%C3%B3mo-establecer-permisos-con-django-api-rest-framework/595#595), y parece que el usuario que lo hizo, consiguió lo mismo o al menos eso entiendo.

Mi pregunta es:

**¿Puedo yo exponer mis diferentes modelos en Django (entre ellos mi modelo de `Users`) para que éstos sean consumidos por terceros o incluso por otras aplicaciones de mi mismo proyecto?**.

Al parecer por el post que dio referencia y por [este artículo](http://ngenworks.com/technology/how-django-rest-framework-changed-my-life/) pensaría que si. ¿Cuales son sus consideraciones?.

Comment: En efecto se puede, lo que estarías creando es una API (Application Programming Interface). Son muy usadas en la actualidad por muchos programas como Twitter, Facebook y Google. El framework que estás citando es el mejor para DJango, lo único que creo deberás tener en cuenta es que debes programar las reglas de tus recursos para no imprimir frases secretas (por ejemplo).

Comment: Es simple poder hacer uso de Django Rest Framework con Django es uno de los mejores frameworks para el caso.
Su aprendizaje es rapido y tambien tiene muchas configuraciones para los datos a mostrar en cada caso.

Comment: Si, es cierto. Y una pregunta adicional. Si solamente es un modelo el que quiero exponer a otros, por ejemplo solo mis usuarios, si yo decido implementar algo como JSONResponse en lugar de RESTFramework (que es mas complejo por lo de los serializers, routes entre otras cosas), ¿también quedarían mis usurios expuestos con JSONResponse para que sean consumidos por terceros? Sé que existe mucha diferencia entre lo que es un JSONResponse y DjangoRESTFramework, pero generar respuestas con JSONResponse ¿puede ser considerado como un pequeño API para que peticiones via http o AJAX los consuman?

Comment: No, en realidad con cualquiera de los 2 puedes limitar que tan extenso o permisible será tu API, puedes incluso sólo dejar un modelo que sirva sólo para consumir datos. Cualquiera de las 2 formas que mencionas son prácticas.

Comment: La siguiente liga puede serte de apoyo: https://godjango.com/blog/working-with-json-and-django/

Comment: Gracias @Chofoteddy aunque por lo que he leido de Django Rest Framework y algunos ejemplitos de tutoriales que he realizado, éste permite tener un mecanismo mas completo o elaborado para exponer recursos de mi aplicación ¿verdad?

Comment: Es totalmente cierto, pues está construido para ello, además que ya incluye seguridad y herramientas que seguro terminaras usando por separado o programando al crear tu propia vista sin dicho framework.

Answer (score 2):

Otra alternativa válida, si tus requerimientos son sencillos y solo de lectura (Y ojo a este *si*, que son muy traicioneros), es simplemente hacer una vista DTLV (De Toda La Vida), que liste tus usuarios en formato `JSON`. Así evitas dependencias de terceros y exportas únicamente los datos que te interesen.

Por ejemplo, si solo te interesa los ID. de usuario y los login, podrías usar una vista como esta:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import auth

def users_list(request):
    User = auth.get_user_model()
    users = User.objects.all()
    response = render(request, 'api/users_list.json', {
        'users': users,
    })
    response['Content-type'] = 'application/json'
    return response
```

y una plantilla como esta:

```
[
{% for u in users %}  { 
    id: "{{ u.id }}", 
    username: "{{ u.username }}"
}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}]
```

*Disclaimer*: Como ya comenté, es una solución minimalista, solo válida para situaciones muy sencillas. Si la cosa se complica, mejor tirar de una solución estándar como `Django Rest Framework` o `Tastypie`.

Comment: claro, en este momento tengo una vista tipo ListView que examina si el request que le llega es tipo json o normalito. y acorde al url que tengamos (<url>/?format=json) me mostrara el json o no. Lo que no se en este momento es si despues necesite mas cosas, pero creo que lo mejor sera apropiar DRF para poder tener un API si es el caso. Muy chevere tu respuesta en json. Sencillita :D. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Yo creo que tu mejor opción es Django Rest Framework. Al principio cuesta un poco entender eso de las rutas, viewsets, serializers, pero si entiendes lo que son Modelos, Vistas, Forms y Rutas, es básicamente lo mismo, solo con diferentes nombres, pero es la misma lógica.

Un `Serializer` sería como un `Form`, una `Viewset` como una `View` y Rutas, Rutas :)

He visto buenos tutoriales en Youtube que seguro te servirán.

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa a DRF, es utilizar [django-tastypie](https://github.com/django-tastypie/django-tastypie), con el cual es simple generar los recursos en base a tus modelos:

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'user'
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get']
```