# Como puedo reutilizar los permisos de django en django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework, permisos

ya he hecho esta pregunta y puede ser canciono pero tengo la esperanza que alguien me ayude, actualmente estoy haciendo un proyecto con django restframework, en el cual voy a tener dos grupos (Maestros, Estudiantes, Colegio) y estos ya tienen sus permisos asignados en django admin.

Como hago para usar los permisos grupales en django rest-framework.

Dejo Parte de Mi Codigo
**Modelo.py**

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    P_LIST = ((1,'Tourist'),(2,'Enterprise'),(3,'Other'))
    Profile = models.IntegerField(choices = P_LIST, default = 1)

class BaseModel(models.Model):
    create = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True, null = False, blank = False)
    update = models.DateField(auto_now = True, null = False, blank = False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class CatLanguage(BaseModel):
    idLanguage = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = False, blank = False)
    Acronym = models.CharField(max_length = 5, null = False)
    Note = models.CharField(max_length = 2500, null = True, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name

class TblGallery(BaseModel):
    IdGallery = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    Location = models.CharField(max_length = 1500, null = False)

    def  __str__(self):
        return str(self.IdGallery)
```

**Serializador y Viesets:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

from django.views import generic

from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication,    BasicAuthentication
from rest_framework import serializers, viewsets, permissions
from rest_framework_jwt.authentication import JSONWebTokenAuthentication

#Models Import
from Base.models import *
from Base.permissions import *

from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication 

class CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication(SessionAuthentication):

    def enforce_csrf(self, request):
        return  # To not perform the csrf check previously happening


"""
class MyUserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('id','Profile','email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password', 'is_superuser')


class MyUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MyUserSerializer
    queryset = MyUser.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return MyUserSerializer


""" 
#Serialiazers
class LanguageSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CatLanguage
        fields = ['idLanguage','Name','Acronym','Note','create','update']


class GallerySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = TblGallery
        fields = ('IdGallery','Location','create','update')


class GalleryDetailSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = TblGalleryDetail
        fields = ('IdGalleryDetail','IdGallery','IdLanguage','Name','Description')

#---------------    ViewSets      ----------------------------------------------
class LanguageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    #authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication, JSONWebTokenAuthentication]
    authentication_classes = (CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
    permissions_classes = [UserPermission]
    queryset = CatLanguage.objects.all()
    serializers_class = LanguageSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return LanguageSerializer

#---------------    
class GalleryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializers_class = GallerySerializer
    queryset = TblGallery.objects.all()

   def get_serializer_class(self):
        return GallerySerializer


class GalleryDetailViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializers_class = GalleryDetailSerializer
    queryset = TblGalleryDetail.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return GalleryDetailSerializer
```

**Dejo los Permissions.py** hay varas class que e intente, ademas ninguno de ellos es para buscar permisos y grupos.

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import PermissionDenied, NotAuthenticated 
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

#---
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def group_required(*group_names):
    """Requires user membership in at least one of the groups passed in."""
    def in_groups(u):
        if u.is_authenticated():
            if bool(u.groups.filter(name__in=group_names)) | u.is_superuser:
                return True
        return False

    return user_passes_test(in_groups, login_url='403')



SAFE_METHODS = ['GET', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS','POST']

class Profile(BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        """
        Return True if the user is the owner of the ..
        """
        if request.method in SAFE_METHODS:
            return False
        elif request.method == 'PUT' or request.method =='POST':
            if request.user.Profile == 1:
                return True
            return False


class UserPermission(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):                                                        
        if view.action == 'list':                                                                   
            return request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.is_admin                        
        elif view.action == 'create':                                                               
            return True                                                                             
        elif view.action in ['retrieve', 'update', 'partial_update', 'destroy']:                    
            return True                                                                             
        else:                                                                                       
            return False                                                                            

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):                                            
        if view.action == 'retrieve':                                                               
            return request.user.is_authenticated() and (obj == request.user or request.user.is_admin)    
        elif view.action in ['update', 'partial_update']:                                           
            return request.user.is_authenticated() and (obj == request.user or request.user.is_admin)    
        elif view.action == 'destroy':
            return request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.Profile == 1                        
        else:
            return False
```

En Fin, Repito lo que trato es leer los persmisos Grupales e individuales de un usuario y en base a eso permitirle, leer, crear, actualizar y eliminar registros.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola Nestor, supongo que te refieres a http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/563/c%C3%B3mo-establecer-permisos-con-django-api-rest-framework Ya marcaste una respuesta correcta, ¿ha cambiado algo desde entonces?

Comment: Gracias por responder pronto, probe los safe methods, pero no solo los permisos que necesitaba, formule otra pregunta dejando parte de codigo y siendo mas especifico. lo que quiero es leer los permisos asignados en el admin, y en base a eso el usario podra, leer, escribir, actualizar o elimina, con los safe_methods se puede hacer pero no se leen los permisos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta con esto:

Ejemplo para el grupo `Estudiante`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import  Group


class StudentPermission(BasePermission):
    group = Group.objects.get(name='Estudiante')    

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        """
        Returns True if the user belongs to the "Estudiante" group
        """
        if request.is_superuser:
            return True

        # toma todos los permisos grupales e individuales del usuario
        user_perms = request.user.get_all_permissions()
        group_perms = []
        group_values = self.group.permissions.prefetch_related('content_type')\
                                            .values('content_type__app_label', 'codename')
        # Se formatea los permisos del grupo 'Estudiantes'
        for p in group_perms: 
            group_perms.append('%s.%s' % (p['content_type__app_label'], p['codename']))
        # Se comparan los permisos, si los del grupo
        # estan contenidos en los del usuario devuelve True
        return set(group_perms).issubset(user_perms)
```

Comment: Genesis Guerrero, con ese código, la clase StudentPermission Buscara al Grupo de Estudiante y sus permisos y los aplicara a todas las Tablas (Viewsets) que lo tengan? Lo Probare obviamente. Gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Si correcto, tendras que crear los otros dos que faltan (Maestros y Colegio) y Aplicar el permission en los viewsets que necesites proteger.